# how to redefine beamer template

Tags: beamer, templates

Until now I was not successful while trying to redefine a beamer template.
In [texwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/259/wie-redefiniere-ich-ein-beamer-template) I found the hint to just use \setbeamertemplate, but this does not work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\setbeamertemplate*{block example begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title example}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title example}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title example}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body example}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body example}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Comment: try to remove the `\AtBeginDocument` stuff

Comment: Welcome to TX.SX, but in your code last `\begin{beamercolorbox}` doesn't have corresponding `\end{beamercolorbox}`, your main text doesn't contain any `frame` and you don't explain what you want to obtain with this redefinition. How can we help you?

Comment: The `\end{beamercolorbox}` remains unchanged, so I does not have to repeat it. `Frame` is also not required as the error message shows yet. `\AtBeginDocument` is also required.

Comment: Addendum: I like to play with some graphical elements, but this is not relevant at the Moment.

Comment: @Jürgen Does it work without `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: No, if I comment it out it leads to `Missing \begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\AtBeginDocument` is not necessary and the command to set a beamer template is `\setbeamertemplate` not `\setbeamertemplate*`. The following code works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title example}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title example}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title example}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body example}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body example}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example}
    Block content.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OMG, the asterisk caused the problem! Small cause, large effect. I will carry on and implement my changes in this template and perhaps come back again. Many thanks for your help!